# Как загрузить gif в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Как вставить gif-картинку в свой проект, что бы она отображалась?

Comment: скопировать файл в проект. думаю самое оно.

Comment: GIF хоть и поддерживается, но считается наихудшим вариантом для графических ресурсов. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: что значит как загружать? опишите кейс откуда/куда. Для чего использовать, должен ли он проигрываться, что вы уже сделали или пытаетесь сделать, как отвечать на ваш вопрос? Ручками.